# How to solve Gitlab oauth with jenkins logging error

Tags: jenkins, oauth, gitlab, continuous-integration

I have configured Jenkins to auth with gitlab,
but i am facing this weird error .
[image: Jenkins error]

The steps i did in jenkins and gitlab in as follows:

GitLab:
[image: gitlab config]

Jenkins:
[image: jenkins config]

I don't know why it's giving me this error. Please help me to solve it.

Edit: I saw that jenkins logs the error messages. I don't know what type of errors are they. Anyone got the same issue and fixed it after?

```
Mar 10, 2023 4:05:37 PM WARNING org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context log
Error while serving http://116.203.18.225:8080/securityRealm/finishLogin
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApiClient.<init>(GitLabApiClient.java:216)
    at org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApi.<init>(GitLabApi.java:442)
    at org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApi.<init>(GitLabApi.java:364)
    at org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApi.<init>(GitLabApi.java:351)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.GitLabAuthenticationToken.<init>(GitLabAuthenticationToken.java:99)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.GitLabSecurityRealm.doFinishLogin(GitLabSecurityRealm.java:350)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:710)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:397)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:401)
```

And

```
Mar 10, 2023 3:35:45 PM WARNING hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler handleException
Caught unhandled exception with ID f342efdf-1cb5-40a4-8f4e-1b7fcfb69e7c
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApiClient.<init>(GitLabApiClient.java:216)
    at org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApi.<init>(GitLabApi.java:442)
    at org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApi.<init>(GitLabApi.java:364)
    at org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApi.<init>(GitLabApi.java:351)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.GitLabAuthenticationToken.<init>(GitLabAuthenticationToken.java:99)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.GitLabSecurityRealm.doFinishLogin(GitLabSecurityRealm.java:350)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:710)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:397)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:409)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:207)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:140)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:558)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:762)
Caused: javax.servlet.ServletException
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:812)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:894)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$2.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:224)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:762)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:894)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:690)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:240)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1665)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:81)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:129)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:94)
    at jenkins.security.AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.java:52)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:54)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:141)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:97)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:63)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:111)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$0(HttpChannel.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.lambda$new$0(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:933)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1077)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue I have given all necessary permission from jenkins and fixed this issue the permissions i have given was 
**api** (Access the authenticated user's API) 
**read_api** (Read Api)
**read_user** (Read the authenticated user's personal information)
**read_repository** (Allows read-only access to the repository)
**write_repository** (Allows read-write access to the repository)
**sudo** (Perform API actions as any user in the system)
**admin_mode** (Admin Mode)
**openid** (Authenticate using OpenID Connect)
**profile** (Allows read-only access to the user's personal information using OpenID Connect)
**email** (Allows read-only access to the user's primary email address using OpenID Connect)
Thanks for you support devs!!!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an error on Jenkins's side. I am not 100% sure, but I think the error is there because Jenkins cannot find gitlab's API address.

In the pictures you provided above, you didn't specify the gitlab's API address (URI). The API URI should be `http://{IP-address}/api/v4` (just append the `/api/v4`).
Also make sure that the API is available on http, or change the address to https.